# How to test if an image is fully loaded with Picasso

Tags: android, asynchronous, picasso

Picasso is asynchronous, so i was wondering if there is any way i can test if an image is fully loaded, before executing any additional code?

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURI).into(ImageView);
// image fully loaded? do something else ..
```

Answer (score 13):

If the image is fully loaded it will be set on the `ImageView` synchronously.

You can use the callback to assert this.

```
final AtomicBoolean loaded = new AtomicBoolean();
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURI).into(imageView, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
  @Override public void onSuccess() {
    loaded.set(true);
  }
});
if (loaded.get()) {
  // The image was immediately available.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using overloaded method `.into(ImageView target, Callback callback)` is appropriate for your case. You can use the base implementation or extend your own like 
Base:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target, new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```

Extended version:

```
package main.java.app.picasso.test;

/**
 * Created by nikola on 9/9/14.
 */
public abstract class TargetCallback implements Callback {
    private ImageView mTarget;

    public abstract void onSuccess(ImageView target);
    public abstract void onError(ImageView target);
    public TargetCallback(ImageView imageView){
        mTarget = imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        onSuccess(mTarget);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        onError(mTarget);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target, new TargetCallback(target) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ImageView target) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ImageView target) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: An image from a particular type of url is not being displayed by picasso. Therefore, I am trying to determine if Picasso was able to download the image in the first place. Can these two call back methods help me determine if download failed, or are they just callback methods for loading image into the image view and has nothing to do with image download? Thanks!

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski I am loading my all images in target to get bitmap. Now i want to know url from which bitmap is loaded.how can i get requesting image url in target ?

Comment: @HarshalBhatt Easiest way is to add `String` argument in the constructor which will hold the url.

Comment: using com.squareup.picasso.Callback() instead of Callback() worked for me!